# Excel Camera Tool - Resize image to 100% scale

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying use an image to display different tables of data using the camera tool.

As a test the below code works,

1. i change the shape formula to a new range, and then i update the shape scale as it doesn't automatically update when the data is on a different sheet

   2.This only works if i click the button twice.  1st click changes the source, but i have to click it a second time to get the scale to reset to 100%

Any ideas why this is?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.Formula = "=Pivots!AS2:BB10"
Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue
Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.Formula = "=Pivots!AS13:BA27"
Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue
Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264522.aspx) is like a magical incantation that I try when things like this happen. It usually doesn't help, but this time it did!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.Formula = "=Pivots!AS2:BB10"
DoEvents
Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue
Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.Formula = "=Pivots!AS13:BA27"
DoEvents
Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue
Shapes("Display").DrawingObject.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
End Sub
```

Comment: I had already tried that,  of course I put it as the fourth line of code thinking the scaling needs to be `pushed through` but now it makes sense and works for me too!  thanks

Comment: I did the same thing, but somehow figured out the correct location when stepping through. Glad I could help.